# T-SQL finding out which row causes the error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that inserts thousands of rows and if there is bad data in any of the rows, it fails. I do the inserts inside a while loop and it would be nice if there is a way I can have it spit out the row at which the stored procedure is failing. The query and the loop is as such:

```
WHILE @rownum > 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.bestsellers (id, name, datastring, country)
    VALUES (@id, @name, @datastring, @country)
END
```

Is there a way to have it spit it out the @id, @name, @datastring, @country data at which it is failing due to bad data?

Comment: Create a process that cleans the data first (try_parse, test DATALENGTH(), etc.) and then runs your process.  Or you can have a process remove data that will fail, insert it into an audit table, and then run the insert with the data that passed the checks.

Comment: That is not possible in my case - this is a process that was handed over to me to fix within this stored proc. Another reason is that @datastring is actually a complete query, that I can't 'parse' until it is actually executed as dyn sql in the next step in the stored proc.

Comment: If at all possible you should consider rewriting this loop based process to insert this as a set of data. RBAR (row by agonizing row) is not very efficient.

Comment: Horrible idea to use a loop/while.  Horrible.  RBAR is horrible.  Do not write RBAR code.  It is a performance killer.  It is bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TRY CATCH structure, and in the CATCH block, raise a custom error message with all the values of your variables and the `@rownum` in it.

Comment: - I need to get the id of the row inside the dbo.bestsellers table. The @rownum is something different, comes from a different table. I've never done try/catch in tsql before.

Comment: But if there is an error on the INSERT, there won't be a row id inside the table because the row won't get inserted.  Anyway, you can get the variables that you are trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Try Catch Block and also log the information in the Catch Block.

Refer this link for sample:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

```
BEGIN TRY  
     { sql_statement | statement_block }  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]  
END CATCH  
[ ; ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following try catch block should work:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    WHILE @rownum > 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.bestsellers (id, name, datastring, country)
        VALUES (@id, @name, @datastring, @country)
    END
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  

    PRINT '================================================';  
    PRINT 'ERROR: @rownum=' + cast(@rownum as varchar) +  ' @name=' + @name + ' @datastring=' + @datastring  + ' @country=' + @country;
    PRINT '================================================';  
    THROW

END CATCH;
```